# localhost vs. remote server htaccess values

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have set up Usbserver as my local webserver on my PC so that the server root is http://localhost:8081/ but all my webprojects are in [http://localhost:8081/WWW/*PHP*/](http://localhost:8081/WWW/_PHP_/) subdirectory of my local server.

Now: all is working fine - all relative paths work as they should but as I play with the .htaccess file and I want to set up my custom 404.php page with relative path like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /php/errors/404.php
```

...it just do not work as expected cos it, of course, points to http://localhost:8081/ instead of, let's say, [http://localhost:8081/WWW/*PHP*/myproject/](http://localhost:8081/WWW/_PHP_/myproject/) that is my actually acting kind-of server root (cos once uploaded to remote server it would become http://myproject.com/).

This would be absolutely fine on remote server but not here on my local server structure. I also try one suggestion like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 ./php/errors/404.php
```

...but it ended up with blank white page with sentence "./php/errors/404.php" displayed.

**QUESTION:** how to write the code in .htaccess "universally", so it would think that root server is in "myproject" directory instead of "http://localhost:8081/" but once uploaded on my remote server, let's say http://myproject.com/ it would still work as normally?

**REMEMBER:** I cannot use rewriting the root of my local server in Usbserver settings cos I have also quantum of other webpages in "[http://localhost:8081/WWW/*PHP*](http://localhost:8081/WWW/_PHP_)" so they all would stop working that way!

I guess there is some kind of RegEx code that would solve this (as I saw many times here on Stackoverflow guys do this kind of stuff that way) but I am quite bad in RegEx myself so without help from others I am "lost".

I searched web already before asking this here: there were many solutions but I did not find any that would actually solve this specific task (most of them suggesting just rewriting server root in my Virtual Server - Usbserver - settings which I cannot do for reason explained above).

I simply need it to work OK on localhost and on remote server afterwards without rewriting my .htaccess code everytime I upload my website to remote server and vice versa.

P.S.: I also noticed that when I set up my custom 404.php page with absolutle path for my local server like:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost:8081/WWW/_PHP_/myproject/php/errors/404.php
```

...it works BUT it change URL to that custom 404 page instead of staying at the original "not existent" URL address - why? Cos with normal not-edited 404 page the URL doe snot change, it stays the same (= that non existent link).

**EDIT - FINAL SOLUTION:**
So after hours of playing, browsing web, searching for any bits of some additional useful information I finally got it working exactly as I wanted - different directory for error pages (404 etc.) specified in case of localhost and remote server, here it is (mind you: it is my own code so it may not look good - I am newbie in .htaccess stuff - but at least it really work for me as I expected it to work):

```
# RULES FOR ERROR PAGES DIRECTORY IN CASE OF localhost:8081
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:8081 [NC]
RewriteRule .? /WWW/_PHP_/myproject/php/errors/404.php [L]

# RULES FOR ERROR PAGES DIRECTORY IN CASE OF remote server (actual webpage on public server)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost:8081 [NC]
RewriteRule .? /php/errors/404.php [L]
```

Comment: why was this question downvoted is really a mistery to me but OK, whatever, guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working solution

```
# RULES FOR ERROR PAGES DIRECTORY IN CASE OF localhost:8081
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:8081 [NC]
RewriteRule .? /WWW/_PHP_/myproject/php/errors/404.php [L]

# RULES FOR ERROR PAGES DIRECTORY IN CASE OF remote server (actual webpage on public server)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost:8081 [NC]
RewriteRule .? /php/errors/404.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative path is not allowed in error document directive. so you can use an absolute path instead of the full url.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /www/_php_/myproject/php/errors/404.php
```

Reference :

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Comment: sorry but this is not solution cos as I stated in my question it would not work both on local host and remote server + I already said I tryed this and yes it worked fine but it was not suitable for my need (read the question, please)

Comment: I think your requirement is out of the question. You will need to use mod-rewrite to achive this. please Read the ErrorDocument documentaion i mentioned above.

Comment: just to avoid misunderstanding here - I am not saying you are wrong or not right (cos you are), I'm only saying that this will not help me + I am waiting **FOR ANY SOLUTION**, so be it RewriteEngine/RewriteCond/RewriteRule combo or anything else that would solve this... ;-)